# Cant get the badge for a single platform in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline with multiple jobs (MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows).

I am able to get the general build status by building on the following url

```
[![Build Status](https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/status/{pipelineName}?branchName=dev)](https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_build/latest?definitionId={definitionId})
```

Please note the parameters `{organization}`, `{project}`, `{pipelineName}`, `{branch}` and `{definitionId}`

However I am not able to show a different badge for any single job/platform in the pipeline. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have 1 build definition for the 3 platforms? If yes, I don't think it's possible, you can only get a badge for build definition, not for a job in the build definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipeline's Badges show the general build status of the pipeline, not a specific job or task.

Create another pipeline and use the new badge.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been updated. It is possible to get the status badge at the job level within Azure Pipelines. This can be configured at the top of the status badge page. The only thing you need to do is make sure that the structure of the YAML pipeline corresponds with what you’re looking for in terms of context.

Comment: Any supporting documentation or references?